# How come it is not possible to do getContext() in Activity

Tags: android

I am having trouble understanding how to use base class methods in Activity class.

My activity is like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

In that class i cannot access `getContext()` but I can access `getContentResolver()` from ContextWrapper class which extends Context class.

How is that possible, if I have access to a child class then logically I should be able to access its parent methods as well.

Thanks!

Comment: *getContentResolver() which extends Context class.* huh ? did you check what is a base class of Activity?

Comment: Your Activity is a context.

Comment: Don't extend `AppCompatActivity`, Do extend `BaseActivity`.

Comment: 1st BaseActivity is not a standard Android Activity. 2nd He should extend AppCompatActivity if he is using the AppCompat library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In that class i cannot access getContext()

That is because [there is no `getContext()` method on `AppCompatActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) or any of its superclasses. Such a method would be pointless, as an `Activity` *is* a `Context`.

Take a look at class hierarchy:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Activities *are* Contexts (or at least they inherit from Context).

Instead of using `getContext()` you can just use `MyActivity.this`.

Hope that helps :)